# Increasing C++ Program CPU Use

Tags: c++, windows, performance, memory-management, cpu

I have a program written in C++ that runs a number of for loops per second without using anything that would make it wait for any reason. It consistently uses 2-10% of the CPU. Is there any way to force it to use more of the CPU and do a greater number of calculations without making the program more complex? Additionally, I compile with C::B on a Windows computer. Essentially, I'm asking whether there is a way to make my program faster by increasing usage of CPU, and if so, how.

Comment: Why am I reading *fork bomb*..

Comment: @karlphillip, why would the CPU consumption matter if I was making a fork bomb? I'm not, but if I was, I would want my processes to take less power, not more. I'm asking because my program is supposed to generate numbers. Also, what did I get a -1 for? My guestion is specific as to the purpose and it's quite useful for enhancement of quality. I've found nothing explaining a solution.

Comment: I have to agree with that one so I'll cancel out the -1 - this question is both clear and at least moderately useful and some research has clearly taken place since the current CPU utilisation stats are there. And tagging windows since that's made clear in the question.

Comment: Sound to me that you don't want to increase CPU consumption but performance. Usually, when synchronous a loop consumes a CPU core. If it does not, often, it's due to wait for resources / OS (e.g., filesystem). On modern architecture, you'd want a to split your computing amongst cores. However, without peeking at your code, might be hard to tell how to.

Comment: If your program has no latency of any kind (no waits), then normally it would use 100% of a single core without any additional steps (i.e. it would use 25% of combined CPU on a 4-core machine). If your program only used 1%-2%, then it is either a 50-100 core machine or you are not telling us something important (i.e. contrary to your belief, your program does have lots of waits).

Comment: Where can I get my grubby little hands on those sweet 50-100 core CPUs. Mmmmmm!

Comment: Post the code (of your for loops at least). I totally agree with @AndreyT. So without the code the discussion is pointless. Most of us (including me) have the code without waits consuming the entire CPU core so until you post the code it is impossible to find out what is different about your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your application has the power (`PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION` access right), you can use [`SetPriorityClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219) to bump up your priortiy (to the usual detriment of all other processes, of course).

You can go `ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` (try this one first), `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS` (be very careful with this one) or `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` (I would strongly suggest that you probably *shouldn't* give this one a shot).

If you try the higher priorities and it's still clocking pretty low, then that's probably because you're not CPU-bound (such as if you're writing data to an output file). If that's the case, you'll probably have to find a way to *make* yourself CPU bound.

Just keep in mind that doing so may not be necessary (or even desirable). If you're running at a higher priority than other threads and you're still not sucking up a lot of CPU, it's probably because Windows has (most likely, rightfully) decided you don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on why it's only using 10% of the CPU. If it's because you're using a multi-CPU machine and your program is using only one CPU, then no, you will have to introduce concurrency into your code to use that additional horsepower.

If it's being limited by something else (e.g. copying data to and from the disk), then you don't need to focus on CPU, you need to focus on whatever the bottleneck is. Most likely, the limiter will be reading from the disk, which you can improve by using better caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 5):

It's really not the program's right or responsibility to demand additional resources from the system. That's the OS' job, as resource scheduler.

If it is necessary to use more CPU time than the OS sees fit, you should request that from the OS using the platform-dependent API. In this case, that seems to be something along the lines of [`SetPriorityClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`SetThreadPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread & giving higher priority to the thread might be one way.

Comment: It uses 10% when at high priority.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++, consider using [Intel Threading Building Block](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/). You can find some examples [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/codesamples.php).

Answer (score 0):

Some profilers give very nice indications of where bottlenecks in your code are.  For example - the CodeAnalyst (for AMD chips only) has the instructions per cycle ratio.  I'm sure intel profilers are similar.

As Billy O'Neal says though, if your runnning on an 8-core, being stuck on 10 percent of cpu is about right.  If this is your problem then Windows msvc++ has a parallel mode (the [parallel patterns library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx)) for the standard algorithms.  This can give parallelisation for free if have written your loops the c++ way (its still your responsibility to make sure your loops are thread safe).  I've not used the msvc version but the `gnu::__parallel_for_each` etc work a treat.